# tensorflow.data.webcam(): "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property message of which has only a getter"

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, html5-video, tensorflow.js

I am using TensorFlow.js in my web application and the input is a camera. In particular, I am using MobileNet to classifying the camera input. [This](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-teachablemachine-codelab/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) tutorial is an inspiration for this app.
There is a video object:

```
<video autoplay playsinline muted id="webcam" width="224" height="224"></video>
```

And I access it in my JavaScript file:

```
const webcamElement = document.getElementById('webcam');
```

And take an image from the video object, convert it into a tensor to later preprocess and predict using the frame:

```
const webcam = await tf.data.webcam(webcamElement);
```

However, when I run the last line above, it results in the following error:
[image: Error Message]

Am I doing something wrong? I tried to run the [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-teachablemachine-codelab/index.html?index=..%2F..index#0) which also used `tf.data.webcam()` and it worked ok.

Comment: Could you please show more of your code ?

Comment: After I restarted my computer and reloaded the webpage, this error disappeared. It's fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error disappeared when I restarted my computer and reloaded the webpage.